# mulitstore wont change store view

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I am trying to setup a multi store with different products on each site. Just one install. All my domains are pointing to the magento install directory.

When following the step by step guide on the magento community it doesnt donanything all sites goto the base site.

I have no access to the vhost or to restart appache.

I have added the text in the .htaccess file.

I have 4 different domains that will all have there iwn store. Eg uniformsatconsomme.co.uk should goto base Kidsatconsomme.co.uk should show kids_consomme website sportsatconsomme.co.uk should show sports_shop website Fashionatconsomme.co.uk should show fashion_shop website

But the all show base. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing you .htaccess file or your index.php file but from the sounds of it you haven't updated your index.php file to run the necessary Magento store.

You'll need to add something like this to the end of your index.php file:

```
$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
switch($serverName) {
    case $serverName == 'uniformsatconsomme.co.uk':
        Mage::run("base", "website");
        break;
    case $serverName == 'kidsatconsomme.co.uk':
        Mage::run("kids_consomme", "store");
        break;
    case $serverName == 'sportsatconsomme.co.uk':
        Mage::run("sports_shop", "store");
        break;
    case $serverName == 'fashionatconsomme.co.uk ':
        Mage::run("fashion_shop", "store");
        break;
    default:
        Mage::run("base", "website");
        break;
}
```

That way the Magento App knows which store/website to run.

Comment: Thank you for your advice the index.php needed changing and appears to be running correctly now.